# Optimization SQL Query For Analytics

Tags: mysql

I have implemented analytics system which is now performing very poorly. To explain it I need to explain table structure queries

I have two innodb tables

Table1: Contains records about hourly stats (stats_id, file_id, time)
Table2: Contains over 8 million rows.

Table 2 structure is

```
full_stats (
    stats_id Int
    file_id Int
    stats_week Int
    stats_month Int
    stats_year Int
    stats_time DATETIME
```

)

What I am trying to do is to calculate the total views from hourly_stats for a given period of time and grouping records by file_id and then I add/update records to full_stats table. On avg it takes 1-2 mins to process one row. I am trying to optimize the queries for better performance.

Here is what I am doing

There are 60% chances that file_id already exists in full_stats for a given week, month and year and 40% chances are that it doesn't exist.

so in the first query I try to update record using following the query

```
UPDATE full_stats 
   SET total_views=XXX 
 WHERE stats_week=XX stats_month=X 
   AND stats_year=YYYY
```

after that I check if affected rows is zero then I insert the record. Once insert or update is done then the record from hourly_stats is removed based on file_id and the given period of time.

Can you give me any suggestion how to optimize queries and reduce the lock rate?

Comment: What kind of indexing have you set up on this table?

Comment: Use SSD joined in RAID array, should speed up the I/O. Seriously? As long as indexes are added, it should work as fast as it could ever do. Any optimization would do little for performance in this case. Maybe you are looking at a total redesign of the system, but no clues can be given here, because if you push in one spot, you lose in another, and too little detail is given to figure out what can be done better.

Comment: I tried to add index on week,month,year but then performance was extremely slow so I had to remove it.

Comment: @Alexander Can you explain bit more about SSD joined? The aim of this task is to gather the file views on hourly, weekly and monthly basis. If I just use full_stats table then most of the time it would be engaged in insert/update queries. Right now large insertion is only performed on hourly_stats.

If you have any better idea of designing this system then please share it with me.

Comment: SSD are hardware drives based on Flash technology. Increased speed is one of their advantages. It was mostly a joke, meaning that in this case a hardware upgrade would be more appropriate.

About indexes, did you add a common index on all 3 fields, week/month/year?

Comment: Yes I added index but then performance was extremely poor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index causes poor performance, when the index has to be rewritten or updated after every insert/update. This is more likely with regular indexes.
However, in your case it sounds like you'd need an unique index anyway. With this you might not have this problem (that much).

Make sure, that your table uses the InnoDB engine and have an unique index on `(stats_year, stats_month, stats_week)`.

Then, instead of doing an update first, then checking for affected rows and inserting if necessary, use [`INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). This way in 40% of the cases you spared yourself the preceeding update statement.
Note though, that the unique index is crucial for this statement!